# How to Prevent Tooltip "Please Fill Out This Field" From Showing After Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to clear all data from the input fields in the form after hitting the submit button. That is working correctly, but there is an annoying `Please Fill Out This Field` tooltip that shows up after clicking on submit:

```js
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".product-suggestion-form-container").click(function(){
              $(".form-div-top").slideToggle();
              $(".dropdown-arrow-top").toggle();
              $(".dropdown-arrow-up-top").toggle();
            })
          });
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".contact-us-form-container").click(function(){
              $(".form-div-bottom").slideToggle();
              $(".dropdown-arrow-bottom").toggle();
              $(".dropdown-arrow-up-bottom").toggle();
            })
          });
          function clearTopForm() {
            $(".form-div-inner-top")[0].reset();
            // return false;
            // $('.form-div-inner-top').children('input').val('')
            // document.forms['.form-div-inner-top'].reset()
            // document.getElementById('input-group-name').value='';
            // document.getElementById('input-group-email-address').value='';
            // document.getElementById('description-of-product-desired').value='';
          }
```

```css
.form-div-top {
  background-color: #f8f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  border-top: none !important;
  padding: 15px;
}

.form-div-top-active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.submit-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.submit-button-1,
.submit-button-2 {
  background-color: #f3c45c;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.submit-button-1:hover,
.submit-button-2:hover {
  background-color: #ddad4e;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submit-button-1 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-div-top">
            <form class="form-div-inner-top">
              <span class="input-group" id="input-group-name">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" class="form-input" required></input>
              </span>
              <span class="input-group" id ="input-group-email-address">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address *" class="form-input" required></input>
              </span>
              <span class="input-group" id="description-of-product-desired">
                <input type="textarea" placeholder="Description of product desired *" class="form-input" required></input>
              </span>
              <div class="submit-button-container">
                <button class="submit-button-1" onclick="clearTopForm()">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

You will notice some of the other things I've tried in the jQuery:

```
$('.form-div-inner-top').children('input').val('')
```

```
document.forms['.form-div-inner-top'].reset()
```

```
document.getElementById('input-group-name').value='';
```

```
document.getElementById('input-group-email-address').value='';
```

```
document.getElementById('description-of-product-desired').value='';
```

But they're all commented-out because none of them have worked.

If there's another way to clear the input fields in the `form-div-inner-top` form, please recommend. Maybe there's another way that won't cause the tooltip to show, or some sort of `prevent` option that will prevent it from showing altogether.

**EDIT**: Using **novalidate** will not work, of course, because the form still has to be valid - all required fields must be filled out in order to submit.

**EDIT 2**: Besides that, I think there's something wrong with `$(".form-div-inner-top")[0].reset();`, because all fields must be filled out in order to hit submit. Right now, you're able to hit submit without filling out all required fields, and then the fields get cleared.

Comment: Just change `onclick=...` for `onsubmit=...` should do. The click event executes before the submit.

Comment: The main reason - I understand that You've reset Your form after form submit. and as it's resetting the form after submit so it again searching for required fields and giving You the notification. So for solution - You need to reset Your form "onSubmit" not "after submit"